# Is there any way to return HTML page in response using spring boot rest controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am getting verify_success as string in response.

Please provide answers for only `@RestController`.

```
@RestController    
// here is method call. verify_success,verify_fail are html pages 
@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
@Operation(summary = "email_Verification", tags = { "auth" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String verifyUser(@Param("code") String code) {
    if (emailService.verify(code)) {
        return "verify_success";
        //i want html response instead of string 
    } else {
        return "verify_fail";
        //i want html response instead of string 
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you return html instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass {

@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
@Operation(summary = "email_Verification", tags = { "auth" })
@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView verifyUser() {
     if (emailService.verify(code)) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("verify_success.html");
        return modelAndView;
            } else {
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("verify_fail.html");
        return modelAndView;
            }
        
    }
}## replace rest controler with controler ##
```

Comment: He is strictly asking solution without RestController.